# How to return a string from a bash function without forking?

Tags: bash

I have my function

```
fun() {
    local result
    ...complex calculations...
    echo "$result"
}
```

Of course I can call it by a command substitution, like

```
something="$(fun)"
```

But this is not what I want to. It does an unneeded forking, i.e. `fun` will be executed in a sub-shell.

I want to use the `$result` without doing a fork.

How can I do it, except the trivial solution (setting a global variable in `fun()`)?

Comment: Why would one use Linux/Unix and fear forking?

Comment: @waltinator Why would one use Linux/Unix not wanting to create good tools?

Comment: What is the problem with the trivial solution? Why should the solution be non-trivial?

Comment: Related: [What shells support "value substitution" like MirBSD Korn Shell?](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/611364)

Comment: If your reason to ask this question is perfomance, the simple, reasonable, readable, fast way is to use a global variable. I don't see why not to do it.

Comment: Use python or other non-shell language.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Switching language for such a basic functionality is overkill. Beside that, I have stomatical problems from python.

Comment: Pass a function (what happens next) to this function. I think this may be called a continuation.

Comment: @thanasisp Works, but overkill. I thought some tricky syntax exists, like using `{...}` instead `(...)` also avoids an unneeded fork.

Comment: @thanasisp Global variables are bad, I won't be able to limitless stack function calls.

Comment: @peterh "I have *stomatical* problems from python" Does python interact with your [artificial anus](https://www.bladderandbowel.org/bowel/stoma/what-is-a-stoma/)? Hope it isn't as bad as it sounds.

Comment: @UncleBilly No, it causes vegetative reflexes. Like that 15 years was not enough to switch from python2 to python3, or the regular string encoding exceptions without an acceptable reason; that the average quality of the available code base is below of PHP what I long tought the absolute minimum. I am sorry, I am typically the most characteristic opensource enthusiast in all cultural environment I take part of; despite that I would be happy if the whole language would simply disappear from all storage of the world.

Answer (score 3):

Give the function the name of a variable to return the result in:

```bsh
foo () {
    declare -n result="$1"

    # stuff that sets result
    result='Hello world'
}

foo myvar1
foo myvar2

# Will print "Hello world" twice:
echo "$myvar1"
echo "$myvar2"
```

The variable `result` is a name reference variable and any reference to it inside the `foo` function will reference the variable whose name is given as the first argument to the function.

This requires `bash` release 4.3 or later.

Comment: This works well. Not very beautiful but still better than an unneeded fork. If no better answer appears, you will get the pipe.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica It's unclear why you want to avoid the fork. If you are calling this function millions of times, then maybe move that loop into the function itself instead?

Comment: Not million, but many thousand times, and I run the whole script from cron in every minute. Beside that, there is also a beautifulness motive.

Comment: Narrator: "he never gave the pipe."

Answer (score 1):

I just use a global to return values from simple functions and grab it right after their invocation. E.g. "OUT"

Like

```
    foo() {
      local a='Hello World'
      a="${a% *}" # some work
      OUT="$a"
    }

   foo; myVar="$OUT"
```

Comment: See also [Are there any conventions for the name of global variable that holds function's result?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/365412)